# React Table scaled Checkbox alignment

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm having some struggles with the placement of a rescaled checkbox in a React table.
The original is on the left, the rescaled on the right.

[image][image]

I'm using the Table from react-bootstrap. Looks something like this:

```
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

table() {
    return(
        <Table striped hover size='sm'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                     <th>
                         <Form.Check className='mycheck' type='checkbox'/>
                     </th>
                     ...
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </Table>
     )
}
```

With css:

```
.mycheck {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.75);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.75);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.75); 
  -o-transform: scale(1.75);
}
```

---

**Tried solutions**

- I tried adding padding, but this is not an ideal solution as for different table sizes and different content length, I need different padding.
- I also tried translating the checkboxes, but again the shift needed is different for different table sizes and content length.

Comment: Can you create a snippet or a fiddle so we can play around with your problem? How did you try with padding? FYI, dynamic design can be achieved with media queries, or even with React/Javascript logic. How did you try translating the checkboxes and how did your try fail? Can you formulate the exact problem you need to solve? Currently the question trusts our judgement to guess what the exact problem is and especially with design that's pretty subjective. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Lajos, thanks for your reply. 
I tried to recreate the issue in JSFiddle, but couldn't reproduce it. Scaling the checkbox in a bootstrap table in JSFIddle behaves as expected, not forcing the checkbox outside the table. 
I therefore feel like it's some css of my local environment clashing. 
I have off the shelve bootstrap and make some edits here and there. 
I want to know what forces the checkbox out of the table, so that I can scale the checkbox without it disappearing from the table.

Comment: I tried translating the checkboxes within the 'mycheck' css (padding & translate within the transform). I also tried translating the checkboxes by changing its className, which then adds a different piece of css doing the same; ``<Form.Check className='mycheck mx-2'>``

Comment: The fact that it didn't happen in Fiddle made me curious. Dove into the element inspector of my browser. Bootstrap's Form.Check creates a box element around the checkbox, those margins were all pretty bad and needed some adjustment. Got it working now reasonably now. Thanks for showing interest

Comment: Niels, I'm happy to help. It seems then that it might be a good idea to test your environment without your CSS/Javascript files, gradually adding them. When the problem starts to appear, then you have probably found the file which causes it.